# Confused On Utilizing SSL

Tags: php, javascript, security, ssl, shared

I have a shared SSL certificate from my web host which (for this posts sake) looks like this:

```
https://some-ssl-cert/mysite
```

Going to that link would go to my site, and display it in `https://` with a green padlock.

The normal site is `http://`

How do I display the main login for the website as `https://`?

Obviously I cannot tell or redirect my users to `https://some-ssl-cert/mysite` so I am very confused on how to implement this.

Lastly, when I need to send sensitive information on other pages that aren't `https://` would I simply send that information to `https://some-ssl-cert/mysite?`

So for instance, if I needed to make a secure ajax request or something would I access the .php file via `https://some-ssl-cert/mysite`?

Comment: You should use `https` for all of your site and set the strict transport security header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I display the main login for the website as https://?

You need an SSL certificate for the host name used for your site. You also need your host to support it.

> Lastly, when I need to send sensitive information on other pages that aren't https:// would I simply send that information to `https://some-ssl-cert/mysite`?

If you need to send sensitive information, then you need to do it over HTTPS. If you are using plain HTTP then you need to redirect to the HTTPS site.

> So for instance, if I needed to make a secure ajax request or something would I access the .php file via `https://some-ssl-cert/mysite`?

The *entire webpage* needs to be served over HTTPS. Otherwise:

- It will be a cross-origin request and the ajax will fail (CORS/JSONP/et al excepted)
- The non-secured page could be interfered with (e.g. JS added that would steal the securely acquired data).

Comment: I see. So essentially I cannot have a secure version of my site as: https://mysite.domain it has to be in that https://some-ssl-cert/mysite format because it's shared. And to get it as https://mysite.domain I need to purchase one, yes? This makes me wonder what the next best thing is. Could I do some hasing and salting with .php? http://www.lightcubesolutions.com/blog/?p=47

Comment: In order: Not without upgrading your hosting. Yes. There isn't a next best thing worth considering. At no time is hashing a suitable alternative for encryption or vice versa. Don't even think about trying to implement encryption with JavaScript – it's really, really hard, investing in SSL is a much better bet.

Comment: Mmmmm. Well lastly then, what is the next best thing besides purchasing my own SSL certificate for login form submissions if hashing isn't suitable?

Comment: "There isn't a next best thing worth considering"

Comment: Thanks man :) - I guess I will just have to use hasing until I can save for an SSL certificate then.